# Accessing variable value initialized in one function from another function in Solidity

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I am creating a smart contract that aims to provide a trustworthy way of getting paid on completion of project, but I am having some issues.

So far, there are three major functions:
createProject(), joinProject() and submitProject()

My project struct is as follows:

```
//Project Model
struct project{
    uint pid;
    address clientAddr;
    string name;
    uint bidAmount;
    string description;
    uint deadline; //record unix timestamp
    address freelancerAddr;
    bool isOpen;
    bool isSubmitted;
    bool isAccepted;
}
```

Now I create a project with the client address:

```
function createProject( uint _pid, string memory _name, 
                        string memory _description, 
                        uint _deadline)  OnlyClient public  payable{
   require(msg.value >= 50,"insufficient funds");
  project storage prj = projects[_pid];
  prj.pid = _pid;
  prj.clientAddr = msg.sender;
  prj.name = _name;
  prj.bidAmount = msg.value;
  prj.description = _description;
  prj.deadline = _deadline;
  prj.isOpen = true;
  prj.isSubmitted = false;
  prj.isAccepted = false;

  projectIDs.push(_pid) -1;
  listProjects.push(_name) -1;

  emit LogRegisterProject(_pid, prj.clientAddr, _name, prj.bidAmount, _description, _deadline, prj.isOpen);
```

}

But the freelanceAddr field is still empty. It's value is only initialized by the following function when a freelancer joins the project:

```
function joinProject (uint _pid, address _freelancerAddr) OnlyFreelancer public {
    require(projects[_pid].isOpen=true,"Project is not open yet");
    projects[_pid].isOpen = false;
    projects[_pid].freelancerAddr = _freelancerAddr;
    emit LogJoinProject(msg.sender, _pid);
}
```

Now, I want to submit the project. But before I do that, I want to check that the person who called the joinProject and the one trying to call submitProject is the same one. So I try doing the following:

```
function submitProject(uint _pid, address _freelancerAddr) OnlyFreelancer public{
        require(projects[_pid].freelancerAddr = msg.sender, "You haven't joined the project");
        projects[_pid].isSubmitted = true;
    }
```

**But it gives me a TypeError: No matching declaration after argument-dependent lookup.**

I can however see that the changes have been saved when I run the getProjectDetails() function after joining a project, and all the states have been saved as well. But it's having problems transferring that value to the associated call in submitProject().

I have seen that Solidity does not allow "null" initialization, so what can I do to resolve this error, or is there any alternative to doing this for the verification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a minor syntax error.

I'd been doing:

```
require(projects[_pid].freelancerAddr = msg.sender, "You haven't joined the project");
```

But, there should have been "==".:

```
require(projects[_pid].freelancerAddr = msg.sender, "You haven't joined the project");
```

I'm very new to Solidity, and had seen single "=" being used in other similar comparisons, so had just been doing the same.

Comment: You will find that in most programming languages, a = (single equal sign) is an assignment operator, whereas a == (double equal sign) is a comparison operator. Your erroneous statement would always pass `true` to the `require` check.

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with the part with other programming languages, but I have seen a single = operator being used even in comparison, so I kind of missed that.

Also, could you explain the part about my erroneous statement always passing true to the require check?

Comment: Solidity was influenced by Javascript and Python, among others. In Python, the statement `if a = 1:` will result in a syntax error. In Javascript however, this syntax is valid and will internally resolve to `true` (try `if (a = 1) console.log(true); else console.log(false);`). Solidity also accepts such inline assignments, which is why your statement didn't throw a parser/syntax error.